# Using inline XSLT for an XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, reflection, inline

I have a XML file and an external XSLT file.

Currently, within my XML I refer to an external XSLT link using an href:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl" ?>
     <mytag>
         <t1> </t1>
         <t2> </t2>
         <t3> <t3>
     <mytag>
```

How can I use inline XSLT instead?  Is this possible?  If yes, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to embed the XSLT inside of your XML.

**XSLT *is an XML file***, so you would just need to make sure that you put it inside of the document element of your XML file, so that the XML file is still well-formed.

In fact, [it is described in the XSLT specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Embedding-Stylesheets):

> ## [2.7 Embedding Stylesheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Embedding-Stylesheets)
>
> Normally an XSLT stylesheet is a complete XML document with the
>   xsl:stylesheet element as the document element. However, an XSLT
>   stylesheet may also be embedded in another resource. Two forms of
>   embedding are possible:
>
> - the XSLT stylesheet may be textually embedded in a non-XML
>     resource, or
> - the xsl:stylesheet element may occur in an XML document other than
>     as the document element.
>
> To facilitate the second form of embedding, the xsl:stylesheet element
>   is allowed to have an ID attribute that specifies a unique identifier.
>
> **NOTE:** In order for such an attribute to be used with the XPath id
>   function, it must actually be declared in the DTD as being an ID.
>
> The following example shows how the xml-stylesheet processing
>   instruction [XML Stylesheet] can be used to allow a document to
>   contain its own stylesheet. The URI reference uses a relative URI with
>   a fragment identifier to locate the xsl:stylesheet element:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="#style1"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc SYSTEM "doc.dtd">
<doc>
<head>
<xsl:stylesheet id="style1"
                version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:import href="doc.xsl"/>
<xsl:template match="id('foo')">
  <fo:block font-weight="bold"><xsl:apply-templates/></fo:block>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet">
  <!-- ignore -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
<para id="foo">
...
</para>
</body>
</doc>
```

> **NOTE:** A stylesheet that is embedded in the document to which it is to
>   be applied or that may be included or imported into an stylesheet that
>   is so embedded typically needs to contain a template rule that
>   specifies that xsl:stylesheet elements are to be ignored.

**Depending on how you plan to leverage it, embedded stylesheets may not be supported.  For instance, in IE 6/7/8.**  [There are some workarounds](http://biglist.com/lists/lists.mulberrytech.com/xsl-list/archives/201001/msg00390.html).

Answer (score 0):

For testing across client-side processors, use a [self-referencing stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/Math/XSL/Overview-tech.html#self-style):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Reference the file name as the href value-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="html5.xml"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                >

<!-- Output HTML doctype with text/html content-type and without XML declaration-->
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" version="" indent="yes" standalone="no" media-type="text/html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />


<!-- Read the children of the stylesheet itself -->
<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Output the HTML markup-->
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="foo">
        <span class="bar">
           <span class="baz">1</span>
        </span>
        <!--Added comment to fill empty node-->
        <span class="placeholder"><xsl:comment/></span>
      </div>

      <!-- Read matching templates -->
      <xsl:apply-templates />
        <!--Add comment to fill empty script tag-->
        <script src="foo.js" type="application/x-javascript"><xsl:comment/></script>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Don't reprint text nodes within the xsl:stylesheet node -->
<xsl:template match="text()"/>

<!-- Read non-namespaced nodes within the xsl:stylesheet node -->
<xsl:template match="//node()[local-name() = name()]">
  <xsl:if test="local-name() = 'foo'">
    <xsl:variable name="foo" select="."/>

    <input type="text" id="{$foo}" value="{$foo}"></input>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<test>
 <foo>A</foo> 
 <foo>B</foo> 
 <foo>C</foo>
</test>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```