# serving xsl in addition to xml to web browser

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, xslt

I have the following `controller method` which successfully sends `xml` text to a web browser in a `spring mvc` app.  The problem is that it just sends the text to the browser and not the formatting so the output in the browser is just a bunch of unformatted text jumbled together. **How can I adjust the following `controller method` so that it also sends an `xsl` stylesheet `style.xsl` to the user's web browser, and so that the content in the user's web browser is successfully formatted by `style.xsl`?**

Here is what I have so far:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "actionName.xml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<byte[]> getXml(ModelMap map, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String xml = "";
    String inputpath = "path\\to\\";
    String filename = "somefile.xml";
    String filepluspath = inputpath+filename;
    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(filepluspath);
    try {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(source,result);
        xml = writer.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    byte[] documentBody = xml.getBytes();
    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "xml"));
    header.setContentLength(documentBody.length);
    return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(documentBody, header);
}
```

Comment: Note that [`application/xml` is pre-defined inside MediaType](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_XML) already. Also, if "somefile.xml" is static it would be easier and more efficient to configure Spring to serve it as a static resource instead of reading and writing to a response inside a controller.

Comment: @kryger Are you saying that there would be no harmful implications if I were to delete the line `header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "xml"));`?

Comment: You could replace it with `header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *direct* answer to your question is "you cannot" - there's not way to send two resources in a single HTTP response.

You can include a link to the XSLT file in the header of the XML file you're returning:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
```

This will make user's browser try to download and apply `./style.xsl` to the data, so your server will need to expose it.

**UPDATE:** The URI to the stylesheet can be arbitrary; if you want to apply the style only when viewing on your page you can make it relative to the URI that serves your document. If your `@RequestMapping` resolves to something like `http://your-server.com/app/actionName.xml` you could add a static resource `http://your-server.com/app/static/style.xsl` to your app and refer to it via

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="static/style.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
```

---

Alternatively, you can embed XSLT directly into the XML data and not worry about URL mapping, but that's a topic for another question [(already answered, by the way)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7132416/1240557).