# XML: not working w/ embedded XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML file, with embedded XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" id = "style1">
        <xsl:import href = "S1000D_compare.xsl"/>
        <xsl:output method="html"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet> 
    <breakfast_menu>
        <food>
           <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
           <price>$5.95</price>
           <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
           <calories>650</calories>
       </food>
       <food>
           <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
           <price>$7.95</price>
           <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
           <calories>900</calories>
       </food>
       <food>
           <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
           <price>$8.95</price>
           <description>Belgian waffles covered with assorted fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
           <calories>900</calories>
       </food>
       <food>
           <name>French Toast</name>
           <price>$4.50</price>
           <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
           <calories>600</calories>
       </food>
       <food>
           <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
           <price>$6.95</price>
           <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
           <calories>950</calories>
       </food>
   </breakfast_menu>
</doc>
```

The imported stylesheet has the following content:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<body>

    <xsl:for-each select = "breakfast_menu/food">
        <p>Food: <xsl:value-of select = "name"/></p>
    </xsl:for-each>

</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In both Chrome and IE, it opens as a document tree, rather than applying the transform and displaying the HTML result.

I added the "doc" root element based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132106/using-inline-xslt-for-an-xml-file). I did run the doc through [an online validator](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0) with no errors.

Comment: The `xsl:import` and `xsl:output` elements do not make sense where you have placed them -- they belong as children of the `xsl:stylesheet` element.  I'm uncertain whether fixing that will actually solve your problem, but it will be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Note, too, that where they are now, the `xsl:import` and `xsl:output` elements do not have an in-scope declaration for the 'xsl' namespace prefix, so even if they made sense in that position, they wouldn't mean what you probably expect them to mean.

Comment: Thanks!  Those were a copy-paste error. (I started writing up my question, tried some things based on similar questions, and then pasted updates into the wrong location.)  They're in the right place in my XML doc, and in the question now.

Comment: When say you expect the browser to "display[] the XML", do you mean you expect it to apply the specified transform and render the html result as html?

Comment: Yes. I'll make that clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there is poor support for embedding XSLT directly into an XML document in the browser world but if you want to do that then you have to take the steps described in your linked answer, you have not taken most of them.

You will have to make sure the XML has an `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction linking to to the embedded `xsl:stylesheet` element that needs to have some `id` attribute defined in an internal DTD subset as an `ID` attribute.

That way I think you can get Mozilla browsers and Chrome to support simple examples like the following (it basically has your XSLT, only with the XPath selection `doc/breakfast_menu/food` corrected to account for the document structure)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#style1"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
  <!ELEMENT xsl:stylesheet (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
    id ID #IMPLIED>
]>
<doc>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" id="style1">
        <xsl:template match="/">        
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Food list</title>
                </head>
                <body>              
                    <xsl:for-each select="doc/breakfast_menu/food">
                        <p>Food: <xsl:value-of select="name"/></p>
                    </xsl:for-each>             
                </body>
            </html> 
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:output method="html"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet> 
    <breakfast_menu>
        <food>
            <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$5.95</price>
            <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
            <calories>650</calories>
        </food>
        <food>
            <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$7.95</price>
            <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
            <calories>900</calories>
        </food>
        <food>
            <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$8.95</price>
            <description>Belgian waffles covered with assorted fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
            <calories>900</calories>
        </food>
        <food>
            <name>French Toast</name>
            <price>$4.50</price>
            <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
            <calories>600</calories>
        </food>
        <food>
            <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
            <price>$6.95</price>
            <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
            <calories>950</calories>
        </food>
    </breakfast_menu>
</doc>
```

This is online at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/test2017050902.xml and works fine for me with current versions of Firefox and Chrome on Windows 10. I don't think Microsoft browsers like Edge or IE have ever supported the embedded `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#style1"?>` processing instruction with an ID attribute.

As for using an imported stylesheet, the following example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#style1"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
  <!ELEMENT xsl:stylesheet (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
    id ID #IMPLIED>
]>
<doc>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" id="style1">
        <xsl:import href="test2017050901.xsl"/>
        <xsl:output method="html"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet> 
    <breakfast_menu>
        <food>
            <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$5.95</price>
            <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
            <calories>650</calories>
        </food>
        <food>
            <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$7.95</price>
            <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
            <calories>900</calories>
        </food>
        <food>
            <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$8.95</price>
            <description>Belgian waffles covered with assorted fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
            <calories>900</calories>
        </food>
        <food>
            <name>French Toast</name>
            <price>$4.50</price>
            <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
            <calories>600</calories>
        </food>
        <food>
            <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
            <price>$6.95</price>
            <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
            <calories>950</calories>
        </food>
    </breakfast_menu>
</doc>
```

with the stylesheet then doing

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">        
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Food list</title>
            </head>
            <body>              
                <xsl:for-each select="doc/breakfast_menu/food">
                    <p>Food: <xsl:value-of select="name"/></p>
                </xsl:for-each>             
            </body>
        </html> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

works fine for me at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/test2017050901.xml only with Mozilla browsers like Firefox, I am not sure why Chrome renders a blank page, I guess it is a bug or lack of support.